# How to capture an image using Frame Grabber device in C#?

Tags: vb.net, camera, usb, frame-grab

Trying to capture image using frame grabber device by implementing G-API, but I am not able to access internal functions from G-API. After creating object, functions still not able to access.
Here is the link for G-API [LINK](https://www.goepel.com/en/automotive-test-solutions/software/goepel-api.html). However, I am not able to create instances of its classes.

Below are my findings:

1)      I have done the declaration as below
       `Dim Compare_full_image As GApiWrapper.Lvds.G_Lvds`

2)      Then in my function I have tried creating its instance as below
       `Capture_full_image = New GApiWrapper.Lvds.G_Lvds()`

3)      I called the function as below
      `Capture_full_image.Lvds_FrameGrabber_CaptureToFile(1, 400, 800, "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures")`

4)      After running the code I am getting below RUN time error

> Error 1: `GApiWrapper.Lvds.G_Lvds.Friend Sub New()` is not accessible in this context because it is `Friend`.

Comment: What is "G-API" (link)? Also, [edit] your question and add the code where you are trying to use it. Nobody here has a crystal ball.

Comment: That looks like VB, not C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the methods will be static so please try accessing using a static class. Hope it helps 
use this:

```
_apiWrapper.GLvdsWrapper.Lvds_FrameGrabber_CaptureToFile(Parameters)
```

Comment: As it was showing friend function error so got bit confused. Thanks a ton,its working